# Rock, Paper, Scissor, Spock, Lizard in python, Player 2 automatically wins

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

for an exercise we need to recreate the game played by the members of the bigbang theory: Rock, Paper, Scissor, Spock, Lizard. I managed to recreate it almost completely, the only problem is: Player 2 automatically wins. Can someone tell me where I need to change the code and also explain why?

```
import sys

t = len(sys.argv)

if(t < 2 or t > 3):
    print("Usage: rpsls.py symbool1 symbool2")
    exit()
i = 1
while (i > 0):
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2]
    a = a.lower()
    b = b.lower()
    if(a != "rock" and a != "paper" and a != "scissor" and a != "lizard" and a != "spock"):
        print("What's that? please use a real symbol!")

    elif(b != "rock" and b != "paper" and b != "scissor" and b != "lizard" and b != "spock"):
        print("What's that? please use a real symbol!")

    else:
        if (a == "paper" and b == "scissor"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "paper" and b == "rock"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "rock" and b == "lizard"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "lizard" and b == "spock"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "spock" and b == "scissors"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "scissor" and b == "lizard"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "lizard" and b == "paper"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "paper" and b == "spock"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "spock" and b == "rock"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == "rock" and b == "scissor"):
            s = True
            i = 0
        else:
            s = False
            i = 0
        if(a == b):
            print("It's a tie!")
            i = 0
            exit()

if(s == True):
        print("Player 1 wins!")
if(s == False):
        print("Player 2 wins!")
```

Comment: Well you can ignore all your if statements except for the second to last one, so if a is rock and b is scissor it will probably let player one win

Comment: how can i let it ignore all the rest?

Comment: You already are, you reassign the values for s and i in that second to last if statement, also note one of your conditions checks against `scissors`

Comment: just as a general tip you could write - a not in ["rock", "paper",....]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your if statements has an else. Only one of the if statements can be true, so that means that all the other else statements are evaluated. The result of that is that the last else statement - which sets s to False - will "win", so player 2 wins.

You should drop all your else statements, and restructure your code as a series of `if...elif...` blocks:

```
   if a == "paper" and b == "scissor":
        s = True
        i = 0
   elif a == "paper" and b == "rock":
```

(Note, if conditions don't need parentheses.)

Comment: preferably also i'd have nested if's so the op doesn't have to keep evaluating if a is equal to paper :)

Comment: so, change all if's to elif and at the end a else?